# How to query an index in Elastic Search for anything that matches

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I found the example below:

```
my_query = 'spaghetti'

es.search(index="test", doc_type="articles", body={"query": {"match": {"content": my_query}}})
```

What if I want to search everything and not just `content`? As in, return anything that contains `my_query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very clear explanation for the same here:
 `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/mapping-all-field.html`

_all is deprecated in 6.0+

If you had to use `_all`, your query would look like this:

```
es.search(index="test", doc_type="articles", body={"query": {"match": {"_all": my_query}}})
```

You have to make sure _all is enabled in the mapping which is clearly mentioned in their documentation.

You can also use `query_string` with wildcards, which you can't with `match`

```
es.search(index="test", doc_type="articles", body={"query": {"query_string": {"query": my_query}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`query_string` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) and do it like this:

```
my_query = 'spaghetti'

es.search(index="test", doc_type="articles", body={"query": {"query_string": {"query": my_query}}})
```